# Sending an email to senders of selected emails in Mail.app

Tags: mail.app, email

I want to select multiple messages in a Mail.app folder by hand, do *X*, and then have a new mail message window appear with all those senders in the "To:" or "Bcc:" field. What is that magical *X* option?

Is it even built in, or do I need to find\write some Applescript? It looks like Automator doesn't have actions to grab senders from mail messages, so that's no way forward.

I am blown away that this is not as simple as selecting the messages and hitting reply. (It's greyed out, if you try.) I found this [discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2742345?start=0&tstart=0) about the same problem, but there was no real answer offered besides "try another email client" and "create rules for incoming mail that auto-replies". Terrible!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this AppleScript (using 10.7.3).

Select the messages you want to reply to before executing the script.

```
tell Application "Mail"
activate
set selectedMessages to selection
set countMessages to (count of selectedMessages)
if countMessages is equal to 0 then
    display alert "No Messages Selected" message "You must select a message first."
else
set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:"My Subject", content:"My Body"}
repeat with i from 1 to countMessages
    set theInput to item i of selectedMessages
set theName to sender of theInput
tell theMessage
    make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {name:theName}
end tell
end repeat
end if
end tell
```

Comment: Aren't you amazing? This really did the trick. It's crazy that this isn't built in, but your script has certainly helped me in the mean-time. I appreciate it.